# how to add string in input feild at curser position using angular 2

Tags: angular, cursor, addition

This is my input field.

```
<input disabled="" type="text" name="Name" #Name="ngModel"
  [(ngModel)]="objEmailTemplates.Name" placeholder="Enter the name"
  class="form-control" required >

objEmailTemplates.Name = "Hi ,your order will be placed on ";
```

I want to add the string `name` and `date` at cursor position so that the output looks like:

```
"Hi 'Piyush', your order will be placed on '22-25-2018' ";
```

How can I do this this in angular 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
objEmailTemplates.Name = "Hi" + varName, your order will be placed on " + varDate;
```

Comment: this would be dynamic. the cursor can be anywhere in text field.